# If A is reducible to its complement, is the converse true as well?

Tags: formal-languages

I was reading a proof that said that if $A \le_{m} \bar{A}$, then it can be inferred that $\bar{A} \le_{m} A$ as well. Is this a logical conclusion, and if so, why? I didn't think this followed with languages A and B, but if B is A's complement, can one make such a statement?

Answer (score 6):

In general whenever $A\le_m B$ via computable function $f$, we automatically have $\bar{A}\le_m \bar{B}$ via the same $f$. The reason is that $x\in A\iff f(x) \in B$ implies that $x \in \bar{A} \iff f(x) \in \bar{B}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can even use the same reduction. Recall that $A \leq_{m} B$ if we can take in instance $I_{A}$ of $A$ and produce an instance $I_{B}$ of $B$ such that $I_{A}$ is a Yes-instance of $A$ *if and only if* $I_{B}$ is a Yes-instance of $B$ (or equivalently $I_{A} \in A \Leftrightarrow I_{B} \in B$ if you prefer).

The key thing to note when we take the two languages to be $A$ and $\bar{A}$ is that the Yes-instances of $A$ are precisely the No-instances of $\bar{A}$ and vice versa.

So if we have this reduction $A \leq_{m} \bar{A}$, then any Yes-instance of $A$ gets mapped to a Yes-instance of $\bar{A}$ *which is also No-instance of $A$*. Say then we take a Yes-instance of $\bar{A}$ - *this is a No-instance of $A$* - the reduction maps it to a No-instance of $\bar{A}$ - *which is a Yes-instance of $A$*.

Thus the reduction maps all the Yes-instances of $\bar{A}$ to Yes-instances of $A$ (because they're also No-to-No for $A$-to-$\bar{A}$). If that's clear, then it should be obvious that the No-instances are taken care of in the same way.

To write it as language membership, we have a reduction $f$ that gives $I \in A \leftrightarrow f(I) \in \bar{A}$ which is the same as $I \notin A \leftrightarrow f(I) \notin \bar{A}$. Then as $X \in A \leftrightarrow X \notin \bar{A}$ (equiv. $X \in \bar{A} \leftrightarrow X \notin A$), we get $I\in\bar{A} \leftrightarrow f(I) \in A$.